# Unix system call to print numbers in ascending then descending order

Tags: c, unix, fork

I have a small program that needs to print some numbers in the following format:

```
0 1 2 3 4
3
2
1
0
```

which I try to accomplish with this C code:

```
int main() {   
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5 && !fork(); i++) {
        printf("%d ", i);
    }

    wait(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

But this prints

```
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
0 1 2
0 1
0
```

and I can't figure out how to omit the extra digits. Can anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: are you required to use `fork`??

Comment: where are the newlines coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each iteration `fork`s a new child.  The parent exits the loop and `wait`s for the child, and the child prints the iteration number.  However, because there was no newline, the characters remain buffered.  However, each `fork` duplicates the buffer in its current state.  So, each child inherits all of the printed values from its ancestors, and waits for its child to die before exiting.  So, just as the last child exits, the buffers look like this:

```
parent:   ""
child-0 : "0 "
child-1 : "0 1 "
child-2 : "0 1 2 "
child-3 : "0 1 2 3 "
child-4 : "0 1 2 3 4 "
```

child-4 exits (because the `wait` will not block), causing its `stdout` buffer to be flushed.  This causes child-3 to return from `wait` and it exits, causing its `stdout` buffer to be flushed.  This continues until the parent exits, so you see the following (all on one line because there were no newlines anywhere):

```
0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 0 1 0
```

To fix this, simply flush the buffer before printing.  This forces the child's copy of the parent's buffer to be output in sequence order, and then the children's own output will appear as they exit in reverse order:

```
int main() {   
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5 && !fork(); i++) {
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("%d ", i);
    }

    wait(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Gives:

```
0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0
```

Comment: Is there a way to consolidate this to one loop?

Comment: !fork() in the for loop can be changed and a line can be inserted above the first printf, other than that everything has to stay the same

Comment: You added newlines to the incorrect output you are getting, so can we assume you also added newlines to the correct example output too?

Answer (score 0):

1. Where is the new line involved?
2. The OS is free to chose one process over the other.
3. Need to consider buffering
4. What are you trying to do